# Passing Self Signed Certificates from .net HiveMQTT Client to Broker

Tags: .net, azure, mqtt, client-certificates

I'm trying to connect to my MQTT cloud broker.

I followed [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/mqtt-publish-and-subscribe-portal) to create the cloud environment.

Now that I have confirmed it's functionality using MQTTX, I wanted to create .Net middleware that acts as a subscribed client, listening and triggering certain actions and events depending on the message type/contents/ect.

I can't seem to connect properly to the resource, I understand that the cloud environment uses self-signed certifications in order to connect to the broker, but I'm not sure how to pass these certs to the broker using HiveMQTT.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Here is a snippet of code:

```
using HiveMQtt.Client;
using HiveMQtt.Client.Options;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using MQTTnet.Client;

class Program
{


    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {


        var clientCertificate = new X509Certificate2("P:\\client1-authnID.pem");
        //var privateKey = RSA.Create();
        //privateKey.ImportPkcs8PrivateKey(File.ReadAllBytes("P:\\client1-authnID.key"), out _);
        var clientCertificateCollection = new X509Certificate2Collection(clientCertificate);
        



        //Hive MQTT Options for connecting
        var options = new HiveMQClientOptions();
        options.Host = "brokerURL";
        options.Port = 8883;
        options.UseTLS = true;

        options.UserName = "client2-authn-ID";
        options.AuthenticationData = null;

        var client = new HiveMQClient(options);    
        
        client.OnMessageReceived += (sender, args) =>
        {
            // Handle Message in args.PublishMessage
            Console.WriteLine("Message Received: {}", args.PublishMessage.PayloadAsString);
        };

        //Connect to the Broker
        var connectResult = await client.ConnectAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);


        //Check the connection
        Console.WriteLine($"Connected: {connectResult.ReasonCode}");


        //// Subscribe
        await client.SubscribeAsync("client2-authn-ID");


        await client.DisconnectAsync();

    }
   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To connect to the MQTT cloud broker, you need to pass the self-signed certificates to the broker using HiveMQTT. Use the certificate chain method to authenticate the client while connecting to the service.

Upload a CA certificate, the immediate parent certificate of the client certificate, to the namespace. Then, configure client authentication settings and connect a client using the client certificate signed by the previously uploaded CA certificate.

To pass self-signed certificates to the `HiveMQTT` client in .NET, configure the client to use the certificates during the TLS handshake process.

[Creating and Using Client Certificates with MQTT](http://www.steves-internet-guide.com/creating-and-using-client-certificates-with-mqtt-and-mosquitto/) .

[image]

[image]

Use the below code to pass the client certificate to the broker using `HiveMQTT`.

```cs
using HiveMQtt.Client;
using HiveMQtt.Client.Options;
using MQTTnet.Client;
using MQTTnet.Client.Options;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var clientCertificate = new X509Certificate2("P:\\client1-authnID.pem");

        var options = new MqttClientOptionsBuilder()
            .WithTcpServer("brokerURL", 8883)
            .WithTls(new MqttClientOptionsBuilderTlsParameters
            {
                UseTls = true,
                SslProtocol = System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls12,
                Certificates = new List<X509Certificate> { clientCertificate },
                AllowUntrustedCertificates = true,
                IgnoreCertificateChainErrors = true,
                IgnoreCertificateRevocationErrors = true
            })
            .WithClientId("client2-authn-ID")
            .Build();

        var factory = new MqttFactory();
        var client = factory.CreateMqttClient();

        client.UseApplicationMessageReceivedHandler(e =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Message Received: " + Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.ApplicationMessage.Payload));
        });

        await client.ConnectAsync(options);
        await client.SubscribeAsync(new List<TopicFilter> { new TopicFilter("client2-authn-ID", MqttQualityOfServiceLevel.AtLeastOnce) });
        await client.DisconnectAsync();
    }
}
```

Replace the `clientCertificate` variable with the path to your client certificate. Then, pass the `clientCertificateCollection` to the `Certificates` property of the `HiveMQClientOptions` object.

Also replace the `brokerURL` and `client2-authn-ID` with your broker URL and client authentication ID.

References taken from [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/mqtt-certificate-chain-client-authentication) and [Publish and subscribe on an MQTT topic using portal - Azure Event Grid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/mqtt-publish-and-subscribe-portal).

Comment: Thank you Rajesh, great insight and much appreciated.

Comment: I apologize for thanking prematurely before implementation, however now that I am at my machine, I would like to start by apologizing for including MQTTnet in the code snippet. I am exclusively to use HiveMQTT to connect to the broker. There is limited compatibility between the two packages. This post was to understand proper configuration and implementation using the HiveMQTT package exclusively.